# Using IntPtr with IComparer<T>

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit, intptr, icomparer

Three related questions here:

- The `IntPtr` structure apparently does not implement `<` and `>` operators. Is there a way to perform this comparison without converting the structure to an int or long?
- Why are the `<` and `>` operators not implemented on this structure?
- I am enumerating windows from a 32 bit process. Windows from 64 bit processes also seem to be included, which is fine. How can I tell whether to use ToInt32 or ToInt64 on the IntPtr structure?

Context: Windows 7 (64 bit), VS 2010, WinForms (32 bit).

The target windows I want to extract include 64 bit apps such as the Windows Sidebar containing gadgets. If I have taken any wrong assumptions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are the < and > operators not implemented on this structure?

Because there is no point (*in most cases*) of comparing if address of a pointer is less or bigger of some other number or other address. By the way IntPtr class provides equality function too.

[IntPtr.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e036c29s.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you said **"most cases"**. Any clues on how to determine whether an instance is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: not sure, but according to the help, it related to the OS platform, son in case you identfy OS is 64bit, use ToInt64(), but I repeat, I'm not sure on this.