# Determining the bitness of an IntPtr instance using EnumChildWindows

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, 32bit-64bit, intptr

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039736/using-intptr-with-icomparert) but decided to re-post focusing on part of the question.

I am enumerating windows using EnumWindows and EnumChildWindows on a 64 bit Windows 7 from a 32 bit WinForms application. Here is the declaration:

```
public delegate int EnumWindowsCallback (System.IntPtr hWnd, System.IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
public static extern bool EnumWindows (EnumWindowsCallback lpEnumCallbackFunc, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows (IntPtr hWnd, EnumWindowsCallback lpEnumCallbackFunc, IntPtr lParam);
```

I send `[Process.GetProcesses()[i].MainWindowHandle]` as a parameter to `[EnumWindows]` to enumerate all child windows of all processes.

When `[EnumChildWindows]` is called, the `[hWnd]` parameter could be a handle to a window running in a 32 or 64 bit process. Since my app is 32 bit, how can I tell whether to call `[hWnd.ToInt32()]` or `[hWnd.ToInt64()]`. I need to call one of the two functions to compare one IntPtr to another.

Context: Windows 7 (64 bit), VS 2010, WinForms (32 bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to do anything special, a `hwnd` is not a pointer its a HANDLE and for this type 64 bit [Windows guarantees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384203.aspx) that only the lower 32 bits are significant so they can be freely shared.

Comment: Finally! Thank you for the answer and MSDN link. Cheers.